# Want to retrieve old value from uitextfield.placeholder

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am saving the placeholder value in textFieldval(Eg. Username)when it goes to if condition it changes to (Username required * ) and it stays the same even for else condition,
I want the old value of placeHolder(Username) in the else condition.
What should we do here?

```
func fieldEmptyError(value: Bool, textField:UITextField){

    let textFieldVal = "\(textField.placeholder!)"

    if (value){
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        pulsate()
        textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "\(textFieldVal) required *", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red, NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)])
    }else {
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "\(textFieldVal)", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that when you are calling this function 'fieldEmptyError' you already have checked for which text field you are calling this function, for example: username textField, so you can add one more parameter to this function which can be as "placeholder" and then pass the static value as per your textfield check. like:

```
func fieldEmptyError(value: Bool, textField:UITextField, placeHolder: String)
```

So if you find your userName field empty you can call this function as:

```
fieldEmptyError(value:true, textField:textField, placeHolder:"Username")
```

The other solution could be when user try to type in textfield, you can reset the placeholder in delegate method of text field. you can use method textFieldDidBeginEditing or textField:shouldChangeCharacterInRange, that is upto your requirement.

Hope it helps..!!

Comment: Thanks Van, I tried with all the methods, They all getted called when we click on the textfield, Is there any method which gets called just after the screen is loaded related to textfield

Comment: no there is no method call on screen load, but if you want you can call them explicitly by calling becomeFirstResponder method on your textField in viewDidLoad method, so that its delegate method will get call.